# pass data/actions between browsercontrol and winform app in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm a web developer by trade, but I'm trying to write a frontend for game emulators.  Since I'm familiar with html/css/javascript, ideally I'd like to do all my layout with that.  What I need to know is if that's going to be a showstopper.  I'll need to do things like when a user clicks an element on the browser control, make the form code launch something based on a specific path.

Is this possible?  If so, is it a terrible idea?  Should I stop now and just use the form designer?

Comment: I think that if you just ditched the browser control and instead redirect your effort to just making a real winforms (I would actually suggest WPF) app, then you will end up with a much better end result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article helped me: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35373/VB-NET-C-and-JavaScript-communication

Specifically:

> Add an import statement like Imports System.Security.Permissions in your form1 (main form).
>   Add a couple of attributes to form1, like:
>
> ```
>     <PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
>     <System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)> _
>     Public Class Form1
>     End Class
> ```

then

> **Calling VB.NET from JavaScript**
>
> Continuing with the last project, add the following lines of code in
>   your form1:
>
> ```
>      Public Sub showVbHelloWorld()
>          MsgBox("Hello world")
>      End Sub
> ```
>
> In your form1 load event, add this line of code
>              Me.WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = Me
>   What this line does is, it exposes your form1 class to the JavaScript on the HTML page. You could expose any class as long as you
>   make it visible to COM and set its permission to fulltrust.
>
> In your HTML page, add a Button, and on its click event, call this function:
>
> ```
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>        function showVbHelloWorld() {
>           window.external.showVbHelloWorld();
>        } 
>     </script>
> ```